# How do I add a button to each cell of the uitableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a program that adds a new cell for every new song that is played. For example if a song is playing, the program will list that information in a cell but as soon as the song changes the new song's information will be added to a new cell, but I also want a button to be added for every new cell. How do I do that? below is what I have tried so far.

```
    // ...

    playButton = UIButton()
    let imageret = "playbutton"
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: imageret), forState: .Normal)

}

func play(sender: UIButton){

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
    var play: Play

    playButton.tag = indexPath.row
    playButton.addTarget(self,action: "play:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    table.addSubview(playButton)

    // ...
```

Comment: adding it programmatically?

Comment: Yes I would like to add it programmatically

Comment: A better option would be to add the button to the prototype cell in your Storyboard. Then you can connect the button's `play:` action to your cell's subclass.

Comment: @blee, Before add a button on your tableview cell need to create Custom tableviewcell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {              

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell  
    let button : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 60, width: 100, height: 24)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "playButton:", for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    button.setTitle("Click Me !", for: .normal)

    //Remove all subviews so the button isn't added twice when reusing the cell.
    for view: UIView in cell.contentView.subviews as! Array<UIView> {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    cell.contentView.addSubview(button)

    return cell;   
}
```

Comment: This code has a few issues. As cells are reused this code keeps adding more and more buttons to the cell. Ensure only one button is ever added to a cell. And the button (or any subview) should always be added to the cell's `contentView`, not directly to the cell.

Comment: @lucaslt89 It's a bad idea to blindly remove all subviews like that. Why not simply reuse any existing button instead of destroying the cell's content? BTW - That isn't an appropriate edit to someone else's answer.

Comment: The user asked to add the button programmatically, so I assume the button is the only component in the cell. I didn't want to create a new answer since this was correct, just with some issues, which I fixed with the edit. Edition goes through a review process, so in this case, it was a good idea to edit an almost correct answer